# Search Function on AngularFireList in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around getting this search function to work. I have it setup right now so it will get the right item when I search it but it's spelling has to be exact including capitalization and punctuation. I want it to be able to get the item regardless of the users search term's capitalization and if they just typed the letter 'b' it will include all items that have a 'b' in the items fields.

I know that I want to query the call to the database since it would be quite heavy to do it on the client side but what do you guys think or how would you go about achieving this?

```
 setFilteredItems() { 

    this.employeeListRef = this.database.list('userProfile', 
    ref=> ref.orderByChild('lastName'));


    this.employeeList = this.employeeListRef.snapshotChanges()
    .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      }
    );

    //if searchterm is null it returns so it can set back the list to all values
    //searchterm is declared in constructor
    if(!this.searchTerm) {
      return;
    }

    //var term = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();

    this.employeeListRef = this.database.list('userProfile', 
    ref => ref.orderByChild('lastName').equalTo(term));


      this.employeeList = this.employeeListRef.snapshotChanges()
      .map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({
            key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
          }))
        }
      );


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) you can get a good idea of how Firebase stores it's records and why `orderByChild` might not work as you expect.

`b` is `98` and `B` is `66`. Their in different positions on the ASCII table.

There are two things you can try to help you access the data in the expression you want.

1. Try converting the searchable data to `lowercase` with the user of [database methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#tolowercase)
2. Use a cloud function and on-write of a record, save a `lowercase` version of that record in the object, then search by that record. An example would be;

   ```
   { lastName: 'Smith', lowercaseLastName: 'smith' }
   ```

You then `orderByChild('lowercaseLastName')`.